# data of MotionActivity is only updated every 3 or 4 secs instead of 0.01 secs

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I've setup a Timer() to update every 0.01 seconds the data of MotionActivity, but it only updates every 3 to 4 seconds. Why?

```
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateWatch), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func updateWatch() {
    if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
        activtyManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main, withHandler: { (data: CMMotionActivity!) in
            print(data)
            if data.stationary == false { some code } }) } else { print("error") }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `startActivityUpdates` more than once?

Comment: How should I do it different

Comment: Don't use a timer. Just call `startActivityUpdates` once. The handler will be called when there's updated activity. You can't control how often data is sent.

Comment: So you can't control to get every millisecond data from it (like with acceleration)